# Hide & show loop with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, settimeout, setinterval

I have a gif animation that will loop forever. However, I don't want it to be visible all the time, so what I basicly need is to give the animation 3 seconds to run once, then hide it and after 10 seconds make it visible again for 3 seconds.

I currently have this, but it isn't working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function autoupdate() {

  $('#bird').delay(3000);
  $('#bird').css('display', 'none'):
  $('#bird').delay(10000);
  $('#bird').css('display', 'block');
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval("autoupdate()", 50);
  }); 
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in Neal's solution as it will hidden for 13 seconds.. not 10. 
I think the following will suit you better, and it does not contain those 50 millis workaround.

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KpuL2/1/)

```
<div id="bird">
    bird
</div>
<script>
     function autoupdate() {

  $('#bird').css('display', 'none');
  setTimeout(function(){$('#bird').css('display', 'block')},10000);
  setTimeout(autoupdate,13000);

  }

 setTimeout(autoupdate,3000);
</script>
```

Comment: my answer will only stay hidden for 10 seconds. read it again ^_^ even count :-P. also yours might be different times every time

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `()`

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(autoupdate, 50);
  });
```

---

Side point: the `.delay(..)` in your code won't do anything.... That is not what it intent it.

Try this instead:

```
function autoupdate() {
  setTimeout(function(){
     $('#bird').css('display', 'none');
     setTimeout(function(){
        $('#bird').css('display', 'block');
        setTimeout(autoupdate, 50);
     }, 10000)
  }, 3000)
}

$(function(){ //same as $(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(autoupdate, 50);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/NYkCr/